# How do you create a parameter list drop down in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, ssrs-2012, business-intelligence

I have always been able to create drop-down list parameters within SSRS that allow the user to dynamically filter their reports based on one or more values selected from the drop-down list box of multiple values.

Translating now over to Power BI I cannot find any documentation to achieve the same functionality.

I've found a method of turning the slicer into a drop down list box. But it only allows for the selection of 1 value at a time. So it essentially seems to me to be more of a drop-down list of radio buttons.

In SSRS I could create a stored procedure that accepted a value and returned a record set filtered on a specific value(s).

I can see how to do this with Power BI as well but the method I've seen demonstrated, forces the user to select a value before the report is loaded and subsequently loads a pre-rendered report template. Which isn't the same.

So how does one go about creating a report that implements a true drop-down list box allowing for selection of 1 or more values to dynamically generate the result in the report?

Reference links are welcome if a simple answer isn't possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Slicers visual

There is an out-of-the-box feature in PowerBI for slicers, but mind that they can only filter the data on chosen values, you cannot change a TSQL query with them as the parameters:

Create a slicer visual (here in a German menu):

[image]

And, as you've already discovered, set it to Dropdown type using the upside down carrot icon on the slicer header:

[image]

[image]

The dropdown list is multi-select by default:

[image]

Hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while making the multiple selections:

[image]

However, you can control Multi-Select behavior under the 'paintbrush.'  When the visual is active, click the paintbrush icon under visualizations, expand 'Selection Controls' and you will see several options to manage your slicer's behaviors:

(in German: "Slicer-Einstellungen")

[image]

##### Filters pane

Additionally, you may want to explore the filters feature, which was in preview at the time of writing the answer but is now a full feature, see the article from 01/10/2023 on [Format filters in Power BI reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-report-filter-preview) if you follow the old link.

*Remark from the future*:

Mind that for the time of writing, in 2019, this answer means that you need new features to get this dropdown on parameter values done. And even the preview filter feature does not allow this, as we can say now in 2024 when checking the link.

##### You cannot change parameter values in a dropdown like you can do in SSRS (at the time of writing the answer in 2019)

Otherwise, the behavior in SSRS where the report loads from data sources using parameters chosen by users either as parameters in stored procedures or incorporated into dynamic SQL is not replicated in PowerBI.  It's true that there are parameters that can be incorporated in that way with the data set refresh - but these are controlled on the data set, not the report, and are not convenient (or appropriate, really) for report viewers to manipulate.

Comment: Thank you. After reviewing your answer and poking around some more; I found the selection controls area you mentioned where I can also explicitly turn the Single Select option off. Am reading your linked reference regarding the filter component currently in beta also. Will likely look into that as well.

Comment: So you say in the end that putting the parameter in the dropdown does not work and the slicer has just the role of a filter on the columns that you want to slice. Then, this is not an answer to the question above, and you should make that clear from the start.

Answer (score 0):

#### "Field parameters" allow what you ask for

After many years, there is an answer to the question.

##### Microsoft guide on the feature

You can do what you ask for, but you need a new Power BI version that has this preview feature and also switch on the "Field parameters" in the "Preview features" in the options. Only then, you can choose the field parameters from the modeling menu in the report preview of Power BI Desktop.

[image]

Follow the guide at [Let report readers use field parameters to change visuals (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-field-parameters) from October 2023 (at least, this was the latest change at the time of writing). Check the video there for a start to see how you can switch the visuals dynamically from within the query, not just from slicing the output of the query.

##### Only composite models are allowed, pure DirectQuery models are not allowed

Mind that you cannot use this in a DirectQuery (!):

> You can't create parameters in live connection data sources without a local model. However, if you use DirectQuery for Power BI semantic models and Analysis Services, you can add a local model to create field parameters. For more information about using DirectQuery for live connections, see [Composite models on Power BI semantic models and Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-composite-models).

Thus, you can now get to what you search for, but in a local model or with the trick of composite models where some smaller table gets imported while the huge tables that are too big to import can still be queried in a DirectQuery. If I read it right, the whole model is than treated as if it was a Tabular model even though some tables are taken from a DirectQuery.

Then, the "Field parameters" preview feature would allow parameters in a Tabular model - be the model composite or only local - that could change the query dynamically.

If you want to change the embedding of the parameters, you would need to code in DAX inside the Tabular model. With "field parameters", you do not have the tools to change the TSQL query itself dynamically on the spot in the Power Query M language. Instead, you can only change the queries inside your Tabular model. And for the Power Query parameters to work, you would still have to set the defaults by hand while you work on the report in Power BI Desktop.

#### Workaround with slicers might be still enough

##### Joined tables are not allowed in my setup

My problem with a model that joins tables of two DirectQuery sources is that I then get an error in the frontend. That means, I have to run just one DirectQuery to get the report to work, and as soon as I change the type of column in Power Query or join two tables in the model view, the report will not work on the Power BI Server, even though it works in the preview inside Power BI Desktop. Therefore, the composite table trick above will not work for me.

If this or something the like happens to you as well, stick to one DirectQuery to get the live data for the report. You can then still have something like a pseudo-dynamic query by with TSQL code that chooses the range of the values that you might want to slice (filter), and then put a slicer visual next to the table visual so that you can filter the table from the dropdown menu.

##### Example

Ask in TSQL for the last 10 days even if you may often just need the last 3 days. Then put a slicer on that date column to choose the days from the dropdown of the last 3 days. And once that you need more or less, you are free to choose any dates you want from the last 10 days.