# How to add a dropdown list with parameters that user chooses and append to API request?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In a power query custom connector I can make the user input some text that gets appended to the url to an API request.

```
// Example in the navigator:
(optional time_range as text) as table => GetSomething(time_range)

// And the actual function
GetSomething = (optional time_range as text) =>
    let 
        _time_range = if time_range <> null then time_range else "medium_term",
        options = [Headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/Json"], Query = [limit = "50", time_range=_time_range]],
        source = Web.Contents("https://example.com/v1/me/", options),
        json = Json.Document(source),
        listOfItems = json[items]
    in
        listOfItems;
```

My goal would be to make the user **select from a dropdown list with those three values** (short, medium, long), instead of making him write and possibly compromise the request.

Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: For those who search for a parametrisation of a TSQL query instead of an API request, see [How do you create a parameter list drop down in Power BI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379300/how-do-you-create-a-parameter-list-drop-down-in-power-bi).

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer in this blogpost:
https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/11/27/specifying-allowed-values-sample-values-and-descriptions-for-function-parameters-in-power-querypart-1/

```
// just add a type for the parameters and enter AllowedValues
GetSomethingParamType = type text 
                            meta [Documentation.Description = "Please enter a time range",
                            Documentation.AllowedValues = {"short_term","medium_term","long_term"}],

// the type for the function
GetSomethingType = type function(
                                           _time_range as GetSomethingParamType) 
                                    as list,

// the type replacement
GetSomethingV2 = Value.ReplaceType(GetSomething, 
                                                   GetSomethingType)
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Did you reach a dropdown here that allows you to select a value - and that value is then taken up in an API to the website "https://example.com/v1/me/" depending on the choice in the menu? Did that work? Why didn't you accept it?